# Why is the set whose elements are a collection of sets equal to the union of that collection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why is {$A_i$ : $i \in I$} = $\bigcup$$_{i \in I} A_i$?

Suppose $I = \{1,2,3\}$, $A_1 = \{a\}$, $A_2 = \{b\}$, and $A_3 = \{c\}$

Then,

- {$A_i : i \in I$} = $\{A_1, A_2, A_3\}$ = $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$
- $\bigcup$$_{i \in I} A_i$ = $\{a,b,c\}$

It doesn't make sense to me that $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$ = $\{a,b,c\}$. These look like two different sets.

Comment: This isn't true.  Who said it was?

Comment: "*It doesn't make sense to me that* ___ ** = ** ___"  Good.  It shouldn't make sense to you because they aren't the same.

Comment: $\bigcup\limits_{i\in I} A_i = \{x~:~\exists i\in I~\text{such that}~x\in A_i\}$

Comment: $\{A_i:i\in I\}\ne\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ but $\bigcup\{A_i:i\in I\}=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$. Could that be what's confusing you?

Comment: Yes, thank you bof and the rest of you guys. It's making more sense now. $\bigcup$$\{A_i : i \in I\}$ is just the short hand for $\bigcup$$_{i \in I} A_i$. I see it now.

Comment: Why would they be equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you have shown that they are indeed not equal.

Indeed $\{\{1\},\{2\}\} \ne \{ 1,2\} $ since $1 \in \{ 1,2\} $ but $1 \notin \{\{1\},\{2\}\}$.